# How to get the integration of QnA maker and the Luis BOT to work accurately?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

The issue I was facing was that I am following this documentation for integrating both LUIS and QnA maker

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis

And I have modified the code for a FAQbot. I have two intents, one the FAQ intent which has the QnA maker and then another Intent.
When I ask a question in the chatbot from the FAQ intent it gives an accurate response and when I ask a completely different question also it goes to the other Intent.
However, when I ask another new question which is not in the knowledge base but has a few words which are similar to the existing questions it gives me an answer predicting it to be from the FAQ intent.
instead of the other intent. How do I improve the accuracy of the model?

```
public class Metadata
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public IList<string> questions { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public double score { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public IList<object> keywords { get; set; }
    public IList<Metadata> metadata { get; set; }
}

public class QnAAnswer
{
    public IList<Answer> answers { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class QnAMakerService
{
    private string qnaServiceHostName;
    private string knowledgeBaseId;
    private string endpointKey;

    public QnAMakerService(string hostName, string kbId, string endpointkey)
    {
        qnaServiceHostName = hostName;
        knowledgeBaseId = kbId;
        endpointKey = endpointkey;

    }
    async Task<string> Post(string uri, string body)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "EndpointKey " + endpointKey);

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            return  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    public async Task<string> GetAnswer(string question)
    {
        string uri = qnaServiceHostName + "/qnamaker/knowledgebases/" + knowledgeBaseId + "/generateAnswer";
        string questionJSON = "{\"question\": \"" + question.Replace("\"","'") +  "\"}";

        var response = await Post(uri, questionJSON);

        var answers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QnAAnswer>(response);
        if (answers.answers.Count > 0)
        {
            return answers.answers[0].answer;
        }
        else
        {
            return "No good match found.";
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class BasicLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    // LUIS Settings
    static string LUIS_appId = "29e08438-43ae-40ab-8a77-7bb6474edd13";
    static string LUIS_apiKey = "95137566e76443019e26a653f99d7a0c";
    static string LUIS_hostRegion = "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com";

    // QnA Maker global settings
    // assumes all KBs are created with same Azure service
    static string qnamaker_endpointKey = "40dfaeb5-5679-4f8f-863f-a5f587101a88";
    static string qnamaker_endpointDomain = "azurebot123";

    // QnA Maker TA_FAQbot Knowledge base
    static string TA_FAQbot_kbID = "13fed287-64d7-43aa-9a39-2c6bc86ea511";


    // Instantiate the knowledge bases
    public QnAMakerService azurebot123QnAService = new QnAMakerService("https://" + qnamaker_endpointDomain + ".azurewebsites.net", TA_FAQbot_kbID, qnamaker_endpointKey);


    public BasicLuisDialog() : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(
        LUIS_appId,
        LUIS_apiKey,
        domain: LUIS_hostRegion)))
    {
    }

    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }


    [LuisIntent("RandomFAQ")]
    public async Task RandomFAQIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

    // TA_FAQbot Intent
    [LuisIntent("TA_FAQbot")]
    public async Task TA_FAQbotIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        // Ask the FAQ knowledge base
        var qnaMakerAnswer = await azurebot123QnAService.GetAnswer(result.Query);
        await context.PostAsync($"{qnaMakerAnswer}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    =
    private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"You have reached {result.Intents[0].Intent}. Sorry, I do not have the answer to this question. I will get back to you with an answer soon.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);

    }

          [LuisIntent("Cancel")]
          public async Task CancelIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
          {
              await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
          }

          [LuisIntent("Help")]
          public async Task HelpIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
       {
              await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
          }
}
```

Comment: Take a look and its important to architect and trained  LUIS in proper way. I think this will guided you about LUIS intent and Entity. Focus on designing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you plan to build a LUIS model, choose a good naming convention. Else It would be hard for you when you referring the particular intent from your code.

Don’t use too lengthy words as intent names. Just use short descriptive wordings. Using Camel case or dot separated phrases is a good practice

**Must Remember About LUIS:**

1. ***Do define distinct intents***

> Make sure the vocabulary for each intent is just for that intent and
>   not overlapping with a different intent

2. ***Do find sweet spot for intents***

> Use prediction data from LUIS to determine if your intents are
>   overlapping. Overlapping intents confuse LUIS. The result is that the
>   top scoring intent is too close to another intent. Because LUIS does
>   not use the exact same path through the data for training each time,
>   an overlapping intent has a chance of being first or second in
>   training

3. ***Balance your utterances across all intents***

> In order for LUIS predictions to be accurate, the quantity of example
>   utterances in each intent (except for the None intent), must be
>   relatively equal.
>
> If you have an intent with 100 example utterances and an intent with
>   20 example utterances, the 100-utterance intent will have a higher
>   rate of prediction

Here are some Do and Don't for LUIS:

[image]

> **Note:** For more details you could refer this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-best-practices#do-and-dont)

**Update:**

[image]

If you still have any query feel free to share in comment. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much! I have followed most of the dos and don'ts as mentioned however the application I am using it for is a FAQ chatbot. So when the user asks a question which is new and not present in the existing question bank but has similar keywords as to the FAQ intent, it gives me the wrong prediction.

Comment: You should omit the closet intent each other. Make a intent different from  each other then trained your model with probable entity I think it will help to get more scored results. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: The intents are not similar to each other but the questions that the end user would ask (utterances) would be close to FAQ intent even though it is not an already existing question present in the FAQ intent. So instead of it replying saying we will get back to you, it will give me another answer from the FAQ intent.

Ill give you an example:

If I ask a question saying "How can I delete my account? "
this question is not present in the KB and thus not an utterance in the FAQ intent however it gives me the answer to "How can I pay using my account?"

Comment: I know man, its also treated as slimier to `LUIS`. In that case   you better keep same `How can I delete my account?` but change `Would you like to pay?`  instead `How can I pay using my account?`. I also encountered the same. Then tried to define precise Intent which does not seems confusing to LUIS. You have to follow techniques here, code seems alright.

Comment: @Ferin If my answer helpful, you could mark it by right click beside the checkbox of your question to help others. Thanks and happy coding.

Comment: But this is going to be up to the end user ( customers) how they type the questions, If they use other questions with similar keywords then how can I control that?

is it possible for you to let me know which part of the code does the searching whether the question asked by user is present in the Knowledge bases from the QnA maker? Maybe if we increase the required accuracy for matching the user inputted question to the existing questions then it will not predict new questions as old ones?

Comment: In that case you could give them button option as I did.

Comment: Could you explain more about the button option?

Comment: @Ferin see the updated answer with bot screen shot. This is how you can confine your user to go what exactly you want. User has to choose between to option. No change to mess

Comment: So we can not give the user full flexibility to ask questions? 
My use case is an FAQ bot so it is very hard to be able to fathom all the questions a user can ask. I wanted to add the liberty for the user to be able to ask new questions to which I would reply saying "I will get back to you" and then reviewing the new questions asked in the endpoint utterances I could decide to add this in the current FAQ database.

Comment: In that case you have to think more with intellectually to define your intent. This is all I can tell now. So that it does not puzzled LUIS

Comment: See I can give user option like `wnat to pay?` or `Want to delete?` But I did not do it, I made a variation while figure out the intent so that it cannot create problem for LUIS.

Comment: Okay, thank you for all the time! I have one more question, is it possible to add email alerts in the chatbot? 
Like if the user asks a random question and it goes to the none intent and says it will get back to you, is it possible to add an email alert there which could be sent to my help desk email?

Comment: @Ferin I guess yes It can be, Using connector on `Azure Logic app` you can do it.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much! I will look into it.

Comment: @Ferin No problem. You are welcome. Microsoft soon release Virtual agent designer  where you could build your bot almost zero coding. Keep in touch.